# Delete and move files

Tags: vb.net, file, stream

Im developing vb.net application framework 4 , i have small problem
process goes like the following before uploading the files ,i will check if the files already exist then i will delete them and then uploading new files. it is works fine only sometime return te following Error **the process cannot access the file because it is being used by anther process**
here is my code

```
 Function MoveFiels(ByVal fn As String) As Boolean
        Dim flg As Boolean
        Application.DoEvents()
        Try
            If File.Exists("des" &  \fn) Then
                File.Delete("des" &  \fn)
                txtErrors.Text &= vbCrLf & "File Deleted and Replace will New File = " & fn & vbCrLf
                Application.DoEvents()
            End If
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            File.Move("source" & \fn, "des" &  \fn)
            flg = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return flg
```

Comment: just because i am curious `File.Move(fn, fn)`? **source** and **destination** are **equal**?

Comment: ooops sorry , actually it is the same files with different location. check in destination location ,if exist delete then move the files.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you sleep the thread

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
```

?
I supposed it must be to give time to your app to delete the file? Maybe some times the time isn't enough and that's why you get the error.
If you just want to wait till the file has been deleted, you can try

```
While System.IO.File.Exists("des" &  \fn)
End While
File.Move("source" & \fn, "des" &  \fn)
```

Comment: thanks for idea ,,,, i missed this point of deleting all existing files first and then move files....... it is work prefect .....